# Swipe to Refresh (Never Disappears)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a swipe to refresh in a Fragment with the following simple code

```
var _swipeRefresh = view.FindViewById<SwipeRefreshLayout>(Resource.Id.swiperefresh);
if (_swipeRefresh != null) {               
    _swipeRefresh.Refresh += (sender, e) => {
        RefreshItems(true);                    
    };
}
```

This works perfectly, and triggers `RefreshItems(true)` function and updates the RecyclerView and adaptor - All good, but the Spinning circle keeps spinning and never disappears.

How do I make it stop spinning after the update is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you define _swipeRefresh as local into oncreate view it access only that block. if define in global _swipeRefresh it access in any where in class.

```
 var _swipeRefresh: SwipeRefreshLayout? = null // as starting on class.
```

after getting value then call below code.

```
                _swipeRefresh?.isRefreshing = false
```

Comment: `_swipeRefresh?.IsRefreshing` does not exist when i initialise it on global level

Comment: _swipeRefresh?.IsRefreshing  in that i is small letter and isRefreshing method is inbulid method for swipeRefreshLayout.

Comment: That is correct, but it does not appear in the list of inbuilt methods by IntelliSense  (Method not found if i force type it)

Answer (score 0):

It will stop animation. It will be called when you could find that items have reached its last limit

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below snippet to disappear SwipeRefreshlayout

```
_swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
```

after

```
RefreshItems(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   _swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
```

You can write this after completion of your process when you get to all the data.

Answer (score 0):

when adapter to get list of value and bind adapter into recycler view then after put below code.

```
_swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
```

Comment: this is what I want but the issue is where I bind data to the recylerview I don't have access to the view `View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment1, container, false);` to find `var _swipeRefresh = view.FindViewById<SwipeRefreshLayout>(Resource.Id.swiperefresh);`